# Do React props and React Native props behave differently?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

At this page [React Native State](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) on React Native docs, we have the following statement:

> props are set by the parent and they are fixed throughout the lifetime of a component.

But, at this page [React State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) on React docs, we have the following statement:

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Where is my misunderstandment? For me the Lifecycle of a component would end when the component is removed from the DOM. So given the first statement i could access the this.props values at any part of my component not only on the render method, but this is not what the second statement says.

Answer (score 2):

The second statement just says that you should not use `this.props` or `this.state` to update your state because multiple updates will be batched by react. If you do e.g. this:

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            aValue: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({aValue: this.state.aValue + 1}); // should be 1 now
        this.setState({aValue: this.state.aValue + 1}); // should be 2 now
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>{this.state.aValue}</p>
        );
    }
}
```

If you do this chances are you end up with a state: `{aValue: 1}` because react will batch your updates leading to the second update overriding your first update, because `this.state.aValue` has not been updated in the moment the second call to `setState()` happens and is still `0`.

Instead you have to pass a function to `setState()` that gets passed the new state and props and returns the next state:

```
this.setState((nextState, nextProps) => ({aValue: nextState.aValue + 1}));
```

There is nothing said about where you can access `this.state` or `this.props`.

Comment: Can i use the props to calculate the first state on the constructor? I think that the components are not recreated everytime they are "rendered".

Comment: Yes that's correct the constructor get's only called once and not on every render. So there you can use the props savely to calculate your initial state.

Comment: Thank you @trixn, i made this question because of the first statement also, it really confused me.

Comment: Great answer. I do think the React docs line OP quotes is misleading as to the safety of updating state from props in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

[React and React Native props](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic) are behaving in completely the same manner. Both are passed from parent to children and shouldn't be mutated (edited) in the child component.